# AngularJS - Highlight specific table rows when using ngRepeat

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Sample Table

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-responsive">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Received</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:search" data-ng-class="<% message.read %>">
        <td>
            <% message.sender.first_name %> <% message.sender.last_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <% message.subject %>
        </td>
        <td>[ TODO ]</td>
        <td>[ TODO ]</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My API returns an array of messages, each message has a `read` boolean attribute. If message.read is false, I want the class for the row to be `success` to highlight all unread messages in the table.

My attempt is incorrect, however what I want to do is populate `data-ng-class="<% message.read %>"` with `data-ng-class="success"`

I have also attempted the following without luck: `data-ng-class="rowClass(message)">`

and in the controller:

```
var messageControllers = angular.module('messageControllers', []);

messageControllers.controller('MessageInboxCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Message',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, Message) {
        $scope.folder = 'Inbox';
        $scope.messages = Message.query();

        $scope.rowClass = (function(message) {
            if (!message.read) return 'success';
            else return '';
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From angular documentation:

ngClass is an expression that will be evaluated. "The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element."

Thus,

```
  data-ng-class="{success: !message.read}"
```

See for an example http://plnkr.co/edit/8zSo5c?p=preview